# vsPackage how to store data

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, vspackage

I'm playing around with vspackages. For now I'm asking how I can implement some kind of a data storage.

Is there a visual studio internal database or somthing which commonly does this? 
I just need it to store some data not much but enough for using very simple small database. Maybe a xml file as storage is a posibility ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from XML which I believe would be a good choice, you can store some data, such as string values and images, in the `Properties` section of your Visual Studio project.

Double click on `Properties` from the Solution Explorer and go to the `Resources` tab. You can then store data in your Resources file (or you'll be given the option to create one first if it does not exist already)